# Is there a glitch in discord.ext

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, praw

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import praw

cl = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = "",
                    client_secret = "",
                    username = "",
                    password = "",
                    user_agent = "")
@cl.event
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot is ready, get ready to do wutever u want with it")

@cl.command()
async def meme(ctx, amount=50, subr="memes", filter="top"):
 all_submission = []
 subreddit = reddit.subreddit("subr")
 subs = subreddit.filter(limit = amount)
 for submission in subs:
   all_submission.append(submission)
 random_sub = random.choice(all_submission)
 name = random_sub.title
 url = random_sub.url
 em = discord.embed(title = name)
 em.set_image = url
 await ctx.send(embed=em)
 print("embed sent")


cl.run("")
```

when I was running this nothing showed up but when I debugged it and !meme in discord it was showing me this traceback error thing

```
It appears that you are using PRAW in an asynchronous environment.
It is strongly recommended to use Async PRAW: https://asyncpraw.readthedocs.io.
Ignoring exception in command meme:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 20, in meme
    subs = subreddit.filter(limit = amount)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/base.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    self._fetch()
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 584, in _fetch
    data = self._fetch_data()
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/subreddit.py", line 581, in _fetch_data
    return self._reddit.request("GET", path, params)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 885, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 330, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 228, in _request_with_retries
    response, saved_exception = self._make_request(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 185, in _make_request
    response = self._rate_limiter.call(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/rate_limit.py", line 33, in call
    kwargs["headers"] = set_header_callback()
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 283, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 425, in refresh
    self._request_token(
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 158, in _request_token
    raise OAuthException(
prawcore.exceptions.OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/memes-bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: OAuthException: invalid_grant error processing request
```

This is the error thing I was talking about and it is very weird like telling me to download async praw which I have never had a problem with and pls help it is needed

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, unlike the `Bot.event` decorator, the `Bot.command` decarator is a function that has to be called, so replace `@cl.command` with `@cl.command()`

Comment: instead of helping it gave me more errors

Comment: What errors did it give you? @NabhayKhanna

Comment: a lot of errors and i cant put it here because the errors exceed the character limit

Comment: Can you either edit the original question or not post the full traceback in the comment but just the error message?